# Exchange 2007 Footers

Tags: email, exchange, exchange-2007

I'm looking at creating a disclaimer footer on Exchange 2007 e-mails.  I'm contemplating on doing this with Transport rules.  However, one concern I had is that if people kept replying to each other on the same message, that this footer would be added to every subsequent message.  You would end up having several duplicate footers in the same message.  How do most people deal with this?  With an exception for the disclaimer text?

Comment: Ugh, disclaimer footers are ridiculous. Don't do it. If your legal counsel is asking you to do this, request that they provide a *single* court case on the books where one of these actually made any difference at all. They're completely useless.

Comment: No, I agree.. they are http://tinyurl.com/3sygwbu .. However management has requested it for specific reasons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transport rule would do it, it is ridiculous, but any question deserves an answer.
I would just add an exception for when the email body contains the disclaimer text.

There's enough flexibility in the transport rules to do whatever you want.

Comment: When you build the Transport Rule, add an Exception to the tune of "except if message body contains <X>" and filter on the disclaimer text. That will prevent the endless build-up of them.

Answer (score 3):

We use a product by Red Earth Software called "Policy Patrol".  Its fairly simple and very reasonably priced and allows us to include html, rtf and plain text signatures.  It also has a 30-day free trial.

We used it for Exchange 2007 and then also Exchange 2010 when we upgraded and have had no issues with it adding simple signatures to our e-mails and it does only include a single signature/footer even when e-mails are forwarded/replied to.

You can also tell it to only add them to external e-mails to avoid bloating internal ones.

I have no affiliation with this company BTW

Answer (score 2):

We use [Exclaimer Mail Disclaimers](http://www.exclaimer.com/products/mail-disclaimers/Default.aspx) and I'm really impressed with it.

Our primary use is to stick on names and contact details from Active Directory, however you could also easily add your disclaimer to it. You can also add a check to see if the disclaimer has already been appended, reducing clutter on the bottom of the email by appending it multiple times.